# Groups audience list shows NONE in Organic Group module

Tags: commerce, organic-groups

In my drupal site i have implemented the [Organic Group](https://www.drupal.org/project/og) module for user group management

1. Here I have created a number of groups like grp1, grp2 ... .
2. I have a custom content type as **Opinion** that has a field **Groups audience** with FIELD TYPE **Entity Reference** so that user can able to post the content type and choose group from **GROUPS AUDIENCE** to which group the post should belong

The issue is when i am adding **Opinion** by admin dashboard  the groups are showing in the list **GROUPS AUDIENCE** as  grp1, grp2 ... and posted to that required group

But when the authenticated user want to post that the **GROUPS AUDIENCE** shows **NONE** , by which after posting the content it is visible in  Home page but not showing the corresponding group page

I have gone through  [this link](https://www.drupal.org/node/1872136)

Also given the full permission to the Role that assigned to the user . Any guidance will help me a lot.

Thanks

Comment: Please don't just ask for "any guidance". Ask precise question, one that can have *specific answer*.

Comment: To add to what @Mołot said, you aren't asking any explicit question, but merely stating facts. Please add an explicit question that is not a request for guidance.

Comment: To be more precise how could I access the group references that the user belong to . so that i can select while posting any content to that target group

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just changed the following to get my work Admin -> structure -> content type -> custom content type(i.e. Opinion) -> manage fields -> changed the WIDGET name to Select list of the field name having FIELD TYPE as Entity Reference